Enforcing Serilog Logging in Public Repository Methods with .NET Architecture Tests
In a .NET 8 web api application, how can I leverage architecture tests using NetArchTest.Rules to ensure every public method in a repository class utilizes Serilog's Information method for logging? The goal is to log the method entry and exit points with relevant details.
Here is what I am looking for in this case :

Every public repository method initiates logging using
_logger.Information() at the beginning.
Each method logs its completion using _logger.Information() at the
end.
Logging messages should include meaningful information about the
method being invoked and any relevant parameters or results.

Code :
using Serilog;

namespace Demo.Repository;

public interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts();
    Product GetProductById(int id);
    // ... other methods
}

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger<ProductRepository> _logger;

    public ProductRepository(ILogger<ProductRepository> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        _logger.Information("GetAllProducts method invoked.");
        // Implement product retrieval logic
        var products = // ... retrieve products
        _logger.Information("Retrieved {0} products.", products.Count());
        return products;
    }

    public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        _logger.Information("GetProductById method invoked for id: {0}.", id);
        // Implement product retrieval logic by id
        var product = // ... retrieve product
        _logger.Information("Product with id {0} {1} retrieved.", id, product?.Name ?? "not found");
        return product;
    }

    // ... other methods
}

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

I don't think architectural tests can and should solve your problem. Architectural tests are all about classes, interfaces, namespaces and dependencies.  They are not about methods implementations.

Looking through the documentation and source code of that library, it appears to be based purely on reflection: looking at the types and method signatures. You could use it to ensure that the repository classes depend on ILogger<>, but you won't be able to use it for much beyond that.
Your first two requirements should be enforceable via a custom Code Analyzer if you feel it's worth the time to pursue that approach. Depending on your definition of "meaningful," the third requirement may be nearly impossible to enforce with current technologies.
If you're going to be super prescriptive, you could probably find other creative ways to encourage or enforce the behavior you're looking for. For example:

You could create a custom helper interface/implementation that standardizes the kind of information you expect to have logged (ID, count, name, etc.), and ensures it gets logged in the format you think it should have. This allows you to make sweeping changes to all of your repository logging at once (e.g. add a property, change the logging framework, change the log level) without having to change code in every repository.
You could enforce that dependency injection for your repository interfaces includes a logging decorator--a class whose sole purpose is to log inputs and outputs. If someone has to write an implementation of a logging decorator method just to get the code to build, they'd kind of have to go out of their way to not add logging code to it. And the business logic can be unit tested without having to mock the logger.
Using a framework like Fody, you could write or configure an IL Weaver that adds logging code automatically, so developers don't even have to think about it with each repository.

That said, I'd question the wisdom in the level of enforcement you're aiming for. If you aren't aligning your practices very closely to your reasons for change, you run the risk of getting in the way of good practices rather than promoting them. Consider:

Logging everything creates a high signal-to-noise ratio, which might make debugging more difficult in common cases. How often will this kind of data actually be useful in tracking down bugs?
If your company decides to change their practices based on new frameworks and tools coming available in the future, you will have scads of logging code that may need to get migrated.
If some repositories deal with sensitive data that shouldn't be logged, you risk running afoul of privacy laws or security compliance.
Will developers find crazy workarounds like putting repositories in a new location just to avoid having to log in certain cases?
Will requiring developers to log the Count() on an IEnumerable<> lead to potentially expensive extra round-trips to the database?

It's often better to teach good principles and leave implementation details like diagnostic logging to developers' discretion rather than being overly prescriptive.

Thanks a lot @StriplingWarrior for sharing the details. It is much helpful to me
